# PHP Return JSON with ? as callback

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I'm trying to return a JSON response like this:

```
 ?([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648]
]);
```

Full example: https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?

Comment: First of all - it's not a JSON. It's a sort of a string.

Answer (score 1):

1. The content type for JSONP is `application/javascript` not `application/json`
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the modern replacement for JSONP. Don't use it with JSONP.
3. You need to use the value of the `callback` query string parameter as the JavaScript function name you are calling. `?` is not a valid function name. jQuery will replace the `?` placeholder in the URL with a real callback name. Use `$_GET['callback']` instead of `"?"`.
4. Don't generate JavaScript data structures by hand. Use `json_encode($some_array)` instead.
5. `Date.UTC(2013,5,2)` is not valid JSON. While it is fine in a JavaScript program, you shouldn't use that in something purporting to be JOSNP. Generate a string representation of your date instead and have client side logic to inflate it into a Date object.

So, without the benefit of having access to your original data, you probably want something along the lines of:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($feedList) . ");";
```

Better yet, switch to:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo json_encode($feedList);
```

… and then fetch it with `XMLHttpRequest` instead of a JSONP approach.

Comment: Thanks for these 4 valuable points.. How do I return the array as in the example shown above? Or is that done automatically?

Comment: Please take a look at this JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

Comment: How would I proceed to duplicate the response from the URL specified in Line #2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode that response with json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Be aware about the depth param when working with arrays

Comment: Thanks! Got any example of how to return that complexed array (as in example)? Do I just push in the values in the array and return the whole array?

Comment: Yep, it does all the magic automatically:

echo json_encode($myArray);

Comment: I understand that json_encode returns like a [] kind of response.. But how do I put [] in ?(   [ ]   );

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: What do mean? it "transform" the php array as a JSON array (or object), so it can be valid when you catch it on the client side with js, it will be a js array.